# Two user access the SqlConnection at same time - Internal connection fatal error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

I have a simple SqlConnection string, on my Asp.Net app

```
 Public Class SQLHelper

 Private Shared _con As SqlConnection

 Public Shared Function Connection(ByVal conStr As String) As SqlConnection
        Try
            _con = New SqlConnection(conStr)
            _con.Open()
            Return _con
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

When two users access the connnection at same time, we get Internal connection fatal error.

Note: If there is difference in seconds, it works fine. Only error occurs when 2 users access the connection at same time Stamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem because you continue using same shared instance of `SqlConnection`.

Do not use shared instance of `SqlConnection`. ADO.NET will manage sqlconnections for you.
Always create new connection for every query you run against database.
If you heard that opening new `SqlConnection` is expensive process, it is true. But ADO.NET will keep connection active and reuse them.
[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Remove `Private Shared _con As SqlConnection` from the class and change you function to this:

```
Public Shared Function CreateConnection(connString As String) As SqlConnection
    Return New SqlConnection(connString)
End Function
```

But now this function seem little bid pointless versus `New SqlConnection(connString)`. Unless you have some other logic inside that function

Comment: make sense, let me try your suggestion and keep posted

Answer (score 0):

I imagine having multiple threads try to use the same SqlConnection simultaneously is causing you problems.

Try replacing your SqlConnection with a property like so:

```
public SqlConnection con { get { return new SqlConnection(connectionString); } }
```

This way, everytime you access con you get a new instance of it pointing to the same database.

Comment: Yes, I was using property still i have the issue

Comment: You wrote it like I did?  Because the code you put in your question is not the same as my code at all.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested, still i have the same issue

Comment: Can you post more of your code?  Show how exactly you are using `con`

Comment: Edited my code as per your suggestion, but still i have the issue